# Is there a way to add a ontap function to bottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have implemented a bottomNavigationBar with its child:TabBar.

As I have multiple layers of navigation within one tab screen, is there a way to have the user tap the tab on the bottomNav and bring them back to the original tab screen?

I have shared the bottom half of my code, I have a tab controller above.

```
bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
      child: MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.2),
          ),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0)),
              color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            ),
            child: TabBar(
              onTap: (index) {
                _tabController.index = _tabController.index;
              },
              labelColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              ),
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                    size: 24.0,
                  ),
                  text: 'Home',
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.edit,
                    size: 24.0,
                  ),
                  text: 'List1',
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.menu_book,
                    size: 24.0,
                  ),
                  text: 'List2',
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    size: 24.0,
                  ),
                  text: 'Profile',
                ),
              ],
              controller: _tabController,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

`TabBar.onTap` is a good place for that:

```dart
TabBar(
  onTap: (index) {
     if (index == _tabController.index) {
       // The user has pressed the selected tab.
       // Access the selected tab's navigator, and pop it back until root
       final navigator = ...
       navigator.popUntil((_) => true);
     }
  }
);
```

Comment: I tried your method but couldn't get it working.

As a work around I used this, which just takes them to the previous page they were on
child: TabBar(
                  onTap: (index) {
                    if (index == _tabController.index) {
                      Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                    }
                  },